(about paintings) "I wanted an original of hers but she never has them available."
Someone is showing around her house, pointing at some printings of paintings on a wall by a famous painter. She says:

I wanted an original of hers but she never has them available.

Christmasy time home decoration
"...she never has them available." caught my attention.
At first, I thought that it might mean the painter paints but never sell them, so she never puts them on sale.
Then I thought it might also mean, she paints them, puts them on sale, they are all sold, but she doesn't paint any new paintings, so no paintings has been available for a very long time.
I think the first one makes more sense, but what about second one?

Are you sure they were paintings and not numbered (limited edtion) color lithographs?

@TimR, I don't know what a color lithograph is. They seemed like reproductions of some paintings to me, which I am not good at understanding. In the video she does not mention anything like numbered (limited edition) or something like that. If you are good at understanding it, I just added the link in the text of the question.

If it is a limited edition, there would be a finite number of "originals" produced from the master. The artist "sells out" of them. That is a context that would make sense of "I wanted an original ... but she never has them available."

If a painter paints and never has their paintings available, what do you think it means? There are only two ways to sell paintings: directly to a buyer OR through a gallery. Conclusion: to make available for purchase by a buyer. These kinds of questions are not about English per se. They could exist in any language.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about English per se.

There's a number disagreement between "an original" and "them" so I think it is indeed a suitable question for ELL.   Why not "never has one available"?

My immediate assumption was she never has them available for me (by implication, as a free or heavily discounted favour for a friend). If you've got the money, even an original by Van Gogh is "available". So until I followed the link, I took it for granted this was a scripted line in a satire of pretentious "social climber art lovers". But apparently it's not a spoof - the speaker is for real!

I tried to watch the video but had to bail at the LED face mask segment, though I wanted out much earlier.

"Never" does not always mean never; we sometimes say "never" for hyperbolic exaggeration. It is possible that originals are sold, and that the speaker has checked a few times and found them to be sold out each time, and they are expressing their frustration by exaggerating. If the painter LITERALLY never sells her original paintings, using "never" to express that is actually more ambiguous than simply saying "she does not sell them."

I would suggest that the sentence simply implies that the artist is producing works, but demand exceeds supply and she never has one for sale when the speaker asks her. It's just a matter of bad luck / timing.

You're correct. If what was intended was that they're put on sale, but always sold out when you try to buy them, it would be more normal to say something like:

but they're never available

"she never has" implies that the painter is avoiding putting them on sale.

There is no 'correct' in an ambiguous statement. Never has THEM available (for sale) implies a policy, whereas 'never has any....' implies that they're sold out. I stand by my guess.

I don't consider the distinction between "any" and "them" to be significant in this case. I think it's the subject of the second clause is more important ("they" versus "she"). But it would be even clearer if it had been written as "she never makes them available"

@lambie is right. This question queries print distribution vs original ownership. FWIW, my guess is that "she never makes them available" so as to protect value of her copies.
